# how to send emails to all users?

Tags: django

How can I send email to all users whenever I want? I have built a blog app and I want to send some emails about news and updates to all the users and I have no idea how to do it. please help me with the code. I'm using the built in django user model for auth. thanks for the responses

Comment: Have you checked out the [Sending Email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/) documentation?

Comment: yes but i dont get it

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly do you not get? It's pretty well documented. It even has code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [send_mass_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail)

An example:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail

all_users = get_user_model().objects.all()
data = [
    ("Subject", "Message", "from@yourdomain.com", [user.email]
    for user in all_users
]
send_mass_mail(data)
```

If you have more than a handful of users, this is generally a pretty naiive approach and might get your mail server blacklisted if you don't know what you're doing. If you're doing mass mailing you should use an email service such as mailgun, sendgrid, etc.

If you want to send HTML content, you must use `send_mail` instead:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.mail import send_mail

all_users = get_user_model().objects.all()
for user in all_users:
    send_mail(
        "Subject",
        "Text message",
        "from@yourdomain.com",
        [user.email],
        html_message="<p>HTML message</p>",
)
```

But this will be more inefficient.

Comment: can I make the email message in a html template and then send that to the users?

Comment: No, not with send_mass_mail. I've edited my example to use send_mail but you should definitely use something like mailgun for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EmailMultiAlternatives` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types)

```
all_users = get_user_model().objects.all()
emails = [user.email for user in all_users]
subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, emails)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```